# Nested aggregation not working with AggregationContainer

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having trouble with Nested aggregations. Here is how I define my aggregations and the json equivalent I get:

```
var aggregations = new AggregationDictionary();

var nestedAgg = new AggregationContainer
{
  Nested = new NestedAggregation("some_name1")
  {
    Path = "users",
    Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("some_name2")
    {
       Field = "users.name.keyword",
       Size = 100,
       Order = new List<TermsOrder> { new TermsOrder() { Key = "_term", Order = SortOrder.Descending } }
    }
};

aggregations[aggKey] = nestedAgg;

searchRequest.Aggregations = aggregations;
```

The above is translated to the following json. it only shows the path and no aggregations definition:

```
{
  "aggs": {
     "some_name1": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "users"
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AggregationDictionary` and `AggregationContainer` directly is a little awkward; You can do so like this

```
var aggregations = new AggregationDictionary();
var aggKey = "some_name1";

AggregationContainer nestedAgg = new NestedAggregation("some_name1")
{
    Path = "users",
    Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("some_name2")
    {
        Field = "users.name.keyword",
        Size = 100,
        Order = new List<TermsOrder> 
        { 
            new TermsOrder() { Key = "_term", Order = Nest.SortOrder.Descending } 
        }
    }
};

aggregations[aggKey] = nestedAgg;

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Test>();

searchRequest.Aggregations = aggregations;

client.Search<Test>(searchRequest);
```

Here we use the implicit conversion from `AggregationBase` (the base class that aggregations derive from) to `AggregationContainer` to assign a `NestedAggregation` to a variable of type `AggregationContainer`.

[This implicit conversion also sets the `Aggregations` and `Meta` properties on `AggregationContainer`, which is why your original attempt doesn't quote work correctly.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/Aggregations/AggregationContainer.cs#L300-L309)

Comment: why is using `AggregationDictionary` and `AggregationContainer` directly awkward? How will I add multiple aggregations to my `SearchRequest`?

Comment: Using directly is a little _awkward_ for a few reasons :) Each aggregation type has a constructor that takes a name (as it's required), but using `AggregationDictionary`, the name of the key will be the name used for the aggregation. Using `AggregationContainer` directly, you need to ensure you also set the `Aggregations` and `Meta` properties when assigning an aggregation, as per the answer. To make things easier, there are implicit conversions from `AggregationBase` to `AggregationContainer` and `AggregationDictionary`.

Comment: You can combine aggregations with `&&`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html